# How do I align the shapes so that the tips are connected with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS3 to create shapes and align them to look like in this image:

[image: here]

I have already made the pink square and the 4 gray rectangles. I could make `div`'s for all the shapes and then adjust the margins and rotations so that it looks like the image. However, that is hard coding it and I don't think that is good practice in CSS.

```
#pinkBlock {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FFC0CB;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

#upRect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#downRect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#leftRect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#rightRect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

Right now, I have 4 gray rectangles stacked on top of each other with a pink block at the bottom. What can I do so that I can have the gray rectangles touch the tips of one another while having that pink block in the middle?

Comment: It would depend what function that the elements will serve. Do they just need to sit there and be visual only? Do they need too scale responsively to the browser size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution using [**`CSS Grid layout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) - see demo below with explanations inline:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: '. up .'
                       'left pink right'
                       '. bottom .'; /* define the layout */
  grid-template-rows: 50px 200px 50px; /* define the row heights */
  grid-template-columns: 50px 200px 50px; /* define the column widths */
}

#pinkBlock {
  background-color: #FFC0CB;
  grid-area: pink;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  justify-self: center; /* align horizontally inside grid item */
  align-self: center; /* align vertically inside grid item */
}

#upRect {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  grid-area: up; /* place this in the layout */
}

#downRect {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  grid-area: bottom; /* place this in the layout */
}

#leftRect {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  grid-area: left; /* place this in the layout */
}

#rightRect {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  grid-area: right; /* place this in the layout */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="pinkBlock"></div>
  <div id="upRect"></div>
  <div id="leftRect"></div>
  <div id="rightRect"></div>
  <div id="downRect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only one element considering multiple background:

```css
.box {
  --d:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(grey,grey) top   / calc(100% - 2*var(--d)) var(--d),
    linear-gradient(grey,grey) bottom/ calc(100% - 2*var(--d)) var(--d),
    linear-gradient(grey,grey) left  / var(--d) calc(100% - 2*var(--d)),
    linear-gradient(grey,grey) right / var(--d) calc(100% - 2*var(--d)),
    linear-gradient(pink,pink) center/var(--d) var(--d);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box" style="--d:40px;">

</div>
```